# Do Subselects make SQlite ignore distincts?

Tags: database, sqlite, select, subquery

we are facing a strange behaviour in SQLite (Version 3).

We have a table for Vehicles with two columns referencing an engine and a gear.
Of course there could be more than one vehicle with the same engine gear combination.

I now want to find the distinct combination of engines and gears of the vehicles (and use it for an insert => thats why randomblob(36)).

Example:

```
Vehicle | EngineId | GearId 
-----------------------------
    1   |     1    |    1
    1   |     1    |    2
    1   |     2    |    1
    1   |     2    |    2
    1   |     1    |    2
    1   |     1    |    2
```

The following select statement results in too many rows:

```
 Select randomblob(36), tmp.EngineId, tmp.GearId from (Select distinct EngineId, GearId from tblVehicle order by EngineId, GearId) as tmp; 


RandomId| EngineId | GearId 
-----------------------------
    1   |     1    |    1
    2   |     1    |    2
    3   |     2    |    1
    4   |     2    |    2
    5   |     1    |    2
    6   |     1    |    2
```

But the expected result would just be:

```
RandomId| EngineId | GearId 
-----------------------------
    1   |     1    |    1
    2   |     1    |    2
    3   |     2    |    1
    4   |     2    |    2
```

If I replace the randomblob(36) with a constant, the result is as expected (of course without a random Id).

Select 2, tmp.EngineId, tmp.GearId from (Select distinct EngineId, GearId from tblVehicle order by EngineId, GearId) as tmp;

Can someone explain me this behaviour of SQLite? Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.

I can reproduce this with SQLite 3.6.23.1 but not with 3.7.15, so it has been fixed already.